# WSO2 GREG 5: how to upload a Word document and associate it with SoapService?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am evaluating WSO2 Governance Registry version 5.
I added some Web services using new Governance Center - Publisher web frontend - it works just fine.

But now I would like to upload a Word document (specification charter) to repository and associate it with my SoapService so it is visible in SoapService detail page.

I found how to do it using console:
http://warunaperera.blogspot.cz/2014/06/how-to-upload-file-and-associate-with.html
It works but such associated document is not visible in Governance Center / Publisher.

So the question is: is it possible with WSO2 Greg to have a Word (or other) documents associated with Soap service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is possible with new GReg 5 series. Please find this [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-develop-governance-registry.html) which explains a basic handler for your requirement.

To get it work you will need to write a handler and publisher/store extensions. There is a [sample handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Handler+Sample) comes with the WSO2 GReg pack. The handler needs to write kind a looks like [swagger handler](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/master/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/SwaggerMediaTypeHandler.java) which comes GReg out of the box. Other than that user wanted to [write a rxt](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance450/Creating+the+Registry+Extension+File) such as wsdl/wadl or swagger rxt. For more information please refer WSO2 Governance registry 5.1.0 [documentation](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/).

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information, we went for another platform so I have not tried this. Sorry for late reaction. But your information is complete and useful, upvoating.